# Input stream is not a valid binary format.

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, serialization, deserialization

in the following I am serializing the class object "ListViewCereal" into a memory stream and then storing the memory stream's buffer to an access database column.

```
    If chkSerialize.Checked = True Then
        Dim cereal As New ListViewCereal                                        'class used to store item list views
        Dim bin_form As New BinaryFormatter                                     'used to serialize and deserialize objects
        Dim file_stream As New MemoryStream                                     'serialization stream
        Dim report_row As DataRow = mycallerPreview.previewInst.SerializedDataDataSet.SavedReportLayouts.NewRow

        cereal.prep_cereal(MoveItemListViewClass1, MoveItemListViewClass2, MoveItemListViewClass3)
        bin_form.Serialize(file_stream, cereal)
        builder.Clear()

        'extract buffer and append string representation of each bit to StringBuilder "builder"
        file_stream.Position = 0
        Dim byteArray() As Byte = file_stream.GetBuffer()
        For Each bit As Byte In byteArray
            builder.Append(bit.ToString)
        Next

        report_row("Serialized Data") = builder.ToString 'column storing string rep. of buffer

        builder.Clear()
        builder.Append(txtYear.Text.ToString).Append("-").Append(txtVendor.Text.ToString).Append("-").Append(txtReport.Text.ToString)
        report_row("Report Name") = builder.ToString
        report_row("User Name") = ""                        'TODO:setup login window to track users
        mycallerPreview.previewInst.SerializedDataDataSet.SavedReportLayouts.AddSavedReportLayoutsRow(report_row)
        mycallerPreview.previewInst.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(mycallerPreview.previewInst.SerializedDataDataSet)

        file_stream.Close()
        file_stream.Dispose()
        mycallerPreview.Show()
        mycallerPreview.previewInst.Close()
        mycallerPreview.previewInst = Nothing
    Else
        mycallerPreview.Show()
        mycallerPreview.previewInst.Close()
        mycallerPreview.previewInst = Nothing
    End If
```

In the following code I attempt to de-serialize the class by referencing the database row/column.

```
       If cmbSavedLayouts.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

        Dim rep_row As DataRow = mycallerSelect2.select_secInst.SerializedDataDataSet.SavedReportLayouts.NewRow
        rep_row = mycallerSelect2.select_secInst.SerializedDataDataSet.SavedReportLayouts.Rows(cmbSavedLayouts.SelectedIndex)
        Dim str As String = rep_row("Serialized Data").ToString
        Dim temp As Byte() = str.Select(AddressOf Byte.Parse).ToArray
        Dim file_stream As New MemoryStream

        file_stream.Write(temp, 0, temp.Count)
        file_stream.Position = 0
        Dim cereal_views As ListViewCereal = CType(bin_form.Deserialize(file_stream), ListViewCereal)
    End If
```

I receive the unhandled exception "Input Stream is not a valid binary format" when I try to deserialize file_stream. I'm fairly new to this so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors. First, there is this:

```
Dim byteArray() As Byte = file_stream.GetBuffer()
```

The buffer is always larger than the stored data; sometimes much larger (by 70-80% !), so that should use `ToArray()` to get just the data.  Next is this:

```
For Each bit As Byte In byteArray
    builder.Append(bit.ToString)
Next
```

I have no idea what `builder` is, but it looks like a `StringBuilder`.  It would be simplest to save the `byteArray` itself and avoid any other conversions. For string storage though, you should use a Base64 string which can easily be converted back to a byte array:

```
Dim serData As String = Convert.ToBase64String(memStrm.ToArray())
```

So, serializing and storing should be something like:

```
Dim B64Data As String
Using ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    bf.Serialize(ms, cereal)
    B64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
End Using

' no idea what this is, just copied it
report_row("Serialized Data") = B64Data
```

Deserializing would be the reverse:

```
' get data, unbox
Dim B64Data = dr.Field(Of String)("Serialized Data")

' I have no idea if these types are correct, just copying them
Dim cereal_views As ListViewCereal
Using ms As New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(B64Data ))
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    cereal_views = CType(bf.Deserialize(ms), ListViewCereal)
End Using
```

Comment: As I expected... I made things more difficult than needed. Thank you for the fast answer this worked like a charm! I also apologize for not clarifying attributes more!

Comment: We all do that - lots of things that seem like good ideas at the time, seem too clever by half in retrospect.